# Stripe won't install dependencies with composer on my website

Tags: php, composer-php, stripe-payments

I am a noob at backend languages and I am surprised I successfully installed composer.

I am using siteground shared hosting and am trying to get stripe working with it. Following stripes documentation, they say to type:

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

Here is the composer file:

```php
{
  "name": "stripe/stripe-php",
  "description": "Stripe PHP Library",
  "keywords": [
    "stripe",
    "payment processing",
    "api"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://stripe.com/",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Stripe and contributors",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/contributors"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "php-coveralls/php-coveralls": "1.*",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Stripe\\" : "lib/" }
  },
  "extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "2.0-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

Error message:

> Problem 1
>           - The requested package stripe/stripe-php No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: Was this composer.json auto-generated by the composer tool or you wrote it yourself?

Comment: It came withe the stripe download.

Comment: Your `composer.json` is incorrect - you should not copy it from library you want to install, but create your own `composer.json` and then use `composer require stripe/stripe-php` to install stripe as dependency.